# Solana SPL token holder count

Tags: spl-token, token, spl-token-program, token-2022, spl

I'm trying to find an efficient way to get the total token holders of an SPL token. For ETH ERC-20 tokens I use Etherscan API, this returns me an integer of the total holders of the token address used in the request.

Bit of a different story for Solana. My current solution is to use Helius API and read out token holders up to 1000 data items at a time. Using pagination I can run the API in a while loop till holders are no longer return (or at least no a 1000) and do an internal tally. Are there any API which can mimic the Etherscan API as it's much more lightweight ?

Comment: You're doing this the right way, there's no better option unfortunately